# Target DataSource dynamically in Weblogic, JMX or another options

Tags: weblogic, datasource, jndi, jmx

As i mentioned in title ;we need to target datasources to their related wepapp on weblogic.
After some googling i could find handling datasources defined before  and deployed .war apps on the server . But i want to match them.
I edited the tutorials below i linked  ,according to my need . But the last and important part is matching datasource with my applications . Is there any alternative way or a tutorial you can point me ?

[Getting datasource properties](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=50)

[Finding available .war file on path and deploy](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=483)

Comment: Can you use WLST to target your datasources? Like this: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=7214

Comment: Thanks for comment but i  wish achieve it  without weblogic script but if this is only way i will try it