# Sample code in java to programmatically target a weblogic library deployment to a server

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, jmx

I have a weblogic (10.3.6) admin server i connect to and i have a library deployed on it ("my-web-libraries"), it is targetted to an existing weblogic server (wlServer1).

Now I created a new weblogic server (wlServer2) and deployed an EAR file on it (programmatically in java using JMX).

The EAR contains a WAR which references my-web-libraries (the reference is mentioned in the EAR's weblogic-application.xml)

All that is missing is to target the existing "my-web-libraries" to the new server i created, programmatically in JMX.

I can't find how to do that in JMX and i am not sure which JMX to connect to (DomainRuntimeServiceMBean/RuntimeServiceMBean/etc...) and which attributes to change for this.

Does anyone have some sample code that targets an application (library archive web logic application) to a web logic server using JMX ?

Thanks

Comment: This is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920571/target-datasource-dynamically-in-weblogic-jmx-or-another-options and I think you're going to have the same problem. You can do it with WLST... you can possibly do it with JMX but the documentation is bad. That said - you could attempt to redeploy the library and target your additional server http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=483

Comment: I want to use JMX to target the library archive. The archive is installed by another product and I don't have control over it (can't re-deploy, can only access it via JMX and add a target)